# Extract data from excel using R

Tags: r, excel, import, extract, xlsx

I have to extract a certain subsection of data from over 100 excel files. The problem is that the total rows across these files are not constant. Is there a way I can stop R from reading data based on a string variable in one of the excel?.

[image: Image given Here]

Comment: are you asking about string variable comparison on a particular cell of excel file?

Comment: Yes. So I would like R to stop reading the table once it finds a certain value in excel. I am using the read.xlsx library and using the current code all rows within the specified columns are read.

Comment: Please provide a clearer example including a sample of the data and the file(s) format.

Comment: I have added an image of the excel file for your reference. I would like to extract the Time record summary table from the excel files. The only catch is that the number of rows in each excel file can vary based on the number of projects different people worked upon. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Do you want to extract the same time record summary from each file?
Is the formatting same in all files?

Comment: Yes. The formatting is same across the files but the number of rows vary across files.

Comment: One way could be to read the complete excel sheet and then discard n top rows. Then search for an empty entry and discard the subsequent rows. Finally discard all but 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can read just the first two columns of each Excel file and then, by exploiting the regularities in the structure of each Excel file, identify and keep just the rows from the first table.

Here's an approach using the `read_excel` function from the `readxl` package to read in the data. We read in only the first two columns of the Excel file. `read_excel` automatically trims white space and starts reading from the first non-empty row.

After reading in the data, we have a data frame with two columns. We now need to make the following changes:

1. Reset the column names to the correct values.
2. Remove the first data row, since those were originally the column names
3. Remove rows after the first table. Since the second table begins with "Time Recording Details", we keep data frame rows only up to the row number that is two less than the row number where this text appears in the first column.

---

```
library(readxl)

# Read first two columns
df = read_excel("Workbook1.xlsx", col_types=c("text","numeric"), range=cell_cols("A:B"))

# Reset column names
names(df) = c("Project", "Hours")

# Remove first row (which contains the column names form the excel file)
df = df[-1, ]

# Remove rows after the end of the first table
df = df[1:(which(df[,1]=="Time Recording Details") - 2), ]
```

Here's the output using the sample Excel file shown below:

```
df
```

> ```
>   Project Hours
> 1       A     1
> 2       B     2
> 3       A     3
> 4       B     4
> 5       A     5
> 6       B     6
> 7       A     7
> ```

To read multiple files, you can read them all into a list of data frames as follows:

```
files = list.files(pattern="xlsx")

df.list = lapply(files, function(f) {

  # Read first two columns
  df = read_excel(f, col_types=c("text","numeric"), range=cell_cols("A:B"))

  # Reset column names
  names(df) = c("Project", "Hours")

  # Remove first row (which contains the column names form the excel file)
  df = df[-1, ]

  # Remove rows after the end of the first table
  df[1:(which(df[,1]=="Time Recording Details") - 2), ]

})
```

Here's a picture of the sample Excel file I created to test the code:

[image]